# How to find a logical value to spot whether dates have the same month and year?

Tags: matlab, datetime, for-loop, if-statement

I have two date vectors and one vector of numbers:

```
% vector 1
t1 = datetime(2002,01,31):calmonths:datetime(2020,12,31);
t1= t1';

% vector 2
t2 = datetime(2002,01,23):calmonths:datetime(2020,12,23);
t2 = t2';
t2(randsample(100,28))=[];

% vector of numbers

r = randn(228,1);
```

What I want to do is, first, to compare *t1* and *t2* to see when they are equal on the basis of months and years and, then, keep only the rows of *r* when this happens.
What I tried was:

```
% first solution

rr = [];
for i = 1:length(r)
if ismember(month(t1(i)) & year(t1(i)), month(t2) & year(t2)) == 1 
    rr(i) = r(i);
else
    rr(i) = NaN;
end
end

% second solution

for i = 1:length(r)  
if any(ismember(month(t1(i)), month(t2))) & any(ismember(year(t1(i)),year(t2)))
    rr(i) = r(i);
else
    rr(i) = NaN;
end
end
```

In either case, it desn't work. It always gives me back 1 even if there there is no match.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

---

I came up with this solution that, however, does the trick to normalise the day for each vector:

```
%  dates
t1 = datetime(2002,1,0)+caldays(indexM);
t2 = datetime(2002,1,0)+caldays(indexI);
% Change day to be the same for all dates for easier comparison
t1.Day=1;
t2.Day=1;
rr=indexM;
% Change to NaN any t1 dates that are not in t2
rr(~ismember(t1,t2))=NaN;

rr
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Are you trying to find when a month and year from t1 are equal to *any* rows of month and year from the t2?  And save those rows where they are? There might be multiple rows returned for this, in which case a simple array result wouldn't suffice unless you know that there could be at most one possible match. Can you provide a short example of t1 and t2 and show us the desired output?

Comment: @JamesTursa I updated the question with a solution that may make you better understand the point I raised.

Comment: How about converting the datetimes into datevecs? Then you can simply test the first and second elements/columns of the vectors.

Comment: @MatteoV I tried that but, I don't understand why, it doesn't work. The only way I managed to make it work is the solutio above where I "normalise" the days

Comment: Your `t2` is shorter than `t1`, how are you expecting to compare the two element-by-element? What happens when you're out of range of `t2`?

Comment: `ismember(A,B)` looks for `A` in any `B`. In my real-dataset, I know that there is at most 1 observation where this can happen